# mariadb No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mariadb

I have problem with, mysql from 11.0.2-MariaDB, client 15.2 when creating minecraft plugin, connecting to database

full error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://172.17.0.1:3306/s1_users
at qbsss.statsmpcore.statssmpcore.StatsSMPCore.onEnable(StatsSMPCore.java:43) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[spigot-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:342) ~[spigot-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot-api-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:525) ~[spigot-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3610-Spigot-6198b5a-19df23a]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:439) ~[spigot-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3610-Spigot-6198b5a-19df23a]
at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.e(DedicatedServer.java:225) ~[spigot-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3610-Spigot-6198b5a-19df23a]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:968) ~[spigot-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3610-Spigot-6198b5a-19df23a]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:293) ~[spigot-1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3610-Spigot-6198b5a-19df23a]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://172.17.0.1:3306/s1_users
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706) ~[java.sql:?]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229) ~[java.sql:?]
at qbsss.statsmpcore.statssmpcore.StatsSMPCore.onEnable(StatsSMPCore.java:38) ~[?:?]
... 9 more

my code:

```
package qbsss.statsmpcore.statssmpcore;

import io.papermc.paper.event.player.AsyncChatCommandDecorateEvent;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import qbsss.statsmpcore.commands.AddZycie;
import qbsss.statsmpcore.commands.Menu;
import qbsss.statsmpcore.events.PlayerKillOtherPlayer;
import xyz.xenondevs.invui.gui.Gui;
import xyz.xenondevs.invui.item.builder.ItemBuilder;
import xyz.xenondevs.invui.item.impl.SimpleItem;

import org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import static qbsss.statsmpcore.methods.Color.color;

public final class StatsSMPCore extends JavaPlugin {


    @Override
    public void onEnable()
    {

        //DATTABASE SETTINGS
        //String databaseUrl = "jdbc:mariadb://172.17.0.1:3306/DB?user=u1_lob9V9Z6iJ&password=@LRV=lP1WWPhzhYlqQqB85Sb";
        //String databaseUser = "u1_lob9V9Z6iJ";
        ///String databasePassword = "@LRV=lP1WWPhzhYlqQqB85Sb";

        //DATABASE CONNECTION

        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mariadb://172.17.0.1:3306/s1_users",
                    "u1_lob9V9Z6iJ", "@LRV=lP1WWPhzhYlqQqB85Sb"
            );
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        //Connection databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl);
            //Connection databaseConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, databaseUser, databasePassword);

            System.out.println(color("&aPolaczono z baza danych"));




        getCommand("menu").setExecutor( new Menu());
        getCommand("addzycie").setExecutor( new AddZycie());

        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerKillOtherPlayer(), this);

        System.out.println("[StatsSMPCore]" +  "&a Witaj Swiecie!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable()
    {
        System.out.println("[StatsSMPCore]" + ChatColor.GREEN + " Goodbye!!!");
    }
}
```

impotrant is to use mariadb so i dont want to change db engine

i tried code thats upper and using mysql jdbc from mysql

Comment: Do you have an appropriate driver-jar on your classpath?

Comment: Is there even a db socket listening on that server?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how a Mine-craft plugin is created, but in my Android app the driver is referenced in Maven like this:

```
implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.3.0'
```